# Monotone convergence and uniform integrability: an application.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> If $E[X_n] < \infty$ for $n = 1,2,\ldots,\infty$ and $X_n$ increases to $X_ \infty$ almost everywhere. Prove that $$E\left[|X_n - X_\infty|\right]\to 0$$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Here's what I tried (but was told it is wrong):

1. $E[X_n] < \infty$ implies that $X$ is bounded outside a set of measure zero (so that $X_n < M$ if $X_\infty < M$) and then do this
   $$E\left[|x_n - x_\infty|\right]  = E\left[|x_n - x_\infty|I\left[|x_n - x_\infty|> \epsilon\right]\right]+ E\left[|x_n - x_\infty|I\left[|x_n - x_\infty|< \epsilon\right]\right]$$ 
   where I is the indicator function.
2. After that using boundedness and that almost everywhere convergence implies convergence in probability
   $$E[|x_n - x_\infty|]  < \epsilon + E[|x_n - x_\infty|I[|x_n - x_\infty|>\epsilon]]   = \epsilon + (2M)P[|x_n - x_\infty|> \epsilon]$$

the later term tends to zero because our sequence converges in probabilty and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the expectation is zero.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like dominated convergence theorem or uniform integrability. Do you have any other assumptions, like $|X_n|\le|X_{\infty}|$ or that $E[X_{\infty}]<\infty$?

Comment: yeah actually its $x_n$ increases to $x_\infty$ and also the expectation of $x_\infty$ is less than infinity

Comment: The it is the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can do the proof in three steps

1. First Step: Since the $X_n$ increase to $X_{\infty}$ then you have by the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) that $$E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X_{\infty}]$$
2. Second Step: Now you know that $$\text{(i) } X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.}X_{\infty},\text{ (ii) } E[X_{\infty}]<\infty,E[X_n]<\infty, \text{ and (iii) }E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X_{\infty}]$$ from the first step. These conditions together imply that the sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ is [uniformly integrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Related_corollaries).
3. Third Step: If $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ is uniformly integrable and$X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.}X_{\infty}$ then you have that $$E|X_n-X_{\infty}|\rightarrow0$$.

Comment: thanks, this seems correct